# How to fix error "Driver does not appear to support OpenGL"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I just installed Minecraft on my pc and I got 1.14.4 installed. Then when I clicked the play in the launcher it disappeared and came back saying

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
```

By the way,

My processor is Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz 2.50GHz

When I went online to get an answer I told me to update but I don't know what generation my processor is. Can somebody please help me out there as well :)

My Display Adapter is Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)

The error log is here

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 27/12/19 10:59 AM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
    at cuo.b(SourceFile:199)
    at cuo$$Lambda$1435/19110518.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1714)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1897)
    at cuo.<init>(SourceFile:81)
    at dnr.a(SourceFile:19)
    at cyc.au(SourceFile:464)
    at cyc.b(SourceFile:394)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:155)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at cuo.b(SourceFile:199)
    at cuo$$Lambda$1435/19110518.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1714)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1897)
    at cuo.<init>(SourceFile:81)
    at dnr.a(SourceFile:19)
    at cyc.au(SourceFile:464)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at cyc.b(SourceFile:394)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:155)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.14.4
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.14.4
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 186042904 bytes (177 MB) / 385875968 bytes (368 MB) up to 838860800 bytes (800 MB)
    CPUs: 2
    JVM Flags: 9 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Xmx800M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
    Launched Version: 1.14.4
    LWJGL: 3.2.2 build 10
    OpenGL: NO CONTEXT
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks
:)

Comment: If your computer is old or cheap, it might just but be able to run Minecraft. Did it work before?

Comment: Pentium? Are you still in the stone ages?!? - Get a new computer!

Comment: @aytimothy There is no need to criticize other user's hardware. There are many reasons people don't use or own better systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll get a new computer @aytimothy

Comment: I was just using a old computer and seeing if it would run Minecraft :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My processor is Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz 2.50GHz

You should upgrade your computer. It is likely due to that your CPU is not supported by newer OpenGL versions. You can play older (pre-1.12) versions fine (but will run like crap), unless they have been updated to use newer graphics libraries.

Today, the current recommendation is that you should be using a CPU on par with at least the third generation of Intel Core processors.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/6xfxus/minecraft_java_editions_system_requirements_have/)